# Succinct and understandable term when "turn up"/"turn down" is ambiguous

Tags: ambiguity, synonyms

In particular, think of the home air conditioner or the power setting on the kitchen refrigerator: the *intensity of effort* is opposite to the *numbering of the related quality*. So "Turn up the air conditioner" can be interpreted as a request to set it colder (make the machine work more) or warmer (change the control to a larger number).

What terms would be good to use instead, that are grammatically equivalent so they are drop-in replacements and don't require re-arranging the sentence, are succinct, and are understandable (even if  not immediatly familiar) by folks lacking a Chirchhillesque vocabulary? And, the whole point is that they are completely unambiguous.  Ideally the pair of terms should match nicely, but that's not necessary.

I know the confusion can be avoided by phrasing it differently, and that's what I actualy do if I notice it. But I've wondered if there's a better term that could be used in this place that is simply not ambiguous at all.

Comment: Given such a context - I would substitute the thing you turn up/down with the result of turning up / down - e.g. "Turn up temperature"

Comment: "Turn up the air conditioner" can be interpreted as a request to set it warmer? Hmm.

Comment: @curious-proofreader: Yes, indeed: set the controller to a higher-numbered position is turning it up.

Comment: Why not just say "raise/lower the temperature setting"?

Comment: What I *could* say (that is, something else) is different from wondering whether there exists a drop-in synonym.

Comment: _Please turn the thermostat up._ or _Please turn the thermostat down._

Comment: Please reopen. Not a dupe. The question this was marked as a dupe of doesn't actually cover "what is a suitable alternative phrase?".

Comment: @AndyT That would be a reasonable question, but I don't think 'What terms would be good to use instead, that are grammatically equivalent so they are drop-in replacements and don't require re-arranging the sentence ... ?' is. Look at the answers offered.   'Turn it to a cooler / ...  setting' is what seems idiomatic, and OP concedes that a rephrasing is sensible here. They also offer no research (eg a Google search for "turn" + "air conditioning").

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, I'd say you turn the air conditioner ***hot*** or ***cold*** instead of up or down.

Comment: "Cold the air conditioner" or "turn cold the air conditioner" doesn't scan to my ear.

Comment: JDługosz, agreed. Hopefully something closer will come up.

Comment: You could talk about _turning the heat_ up and down. If the ambient temperature was low turning the heat up would mean an increase in the work the heating system was doing, if the ambient temperature was high turning the the heat down would mean an increase in the work the AC was doing.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know an existing idiom, but I think **increase** vs **decrease** or **reduce** would work.

> [**increase**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/increase) verb (used with object), increased, increasing.
>   1. **to make greater, as in** number, size, **strength, or quality; augment**; add to
>   —Dictionary.com, emphasis added; antonym *decrease*

So when the air conditioning is running (the system used to *cool* inside air) and you want to say "make it even cooler" you could say

> Please increase the A/C.

and if instead you want to say "stop making it so cold in here" or "set the A/C so it aims for a less-cool temperature" (but *not* "turn on the heating system") you could say

> Please decrease/reduce the A/C.

I think strengthen/weaken would also be understandable, but sound a less natural to me in this context.